# Syntax error while changing Font

Tags: string, android-activity, syntax, fonts, assets

I'm trying to change the Font of a textView (in my case custom_font)
but if gives the 2 error on this line:

```
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

At the (dot) it says:
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

At (Font) it says:

Syntax error on token "font", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

I have no idea how to fix it, i would be nice if anyone would help me :)

Thanks in advance.

MainActivity:

```
package com.test.testforStack;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/hallo.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move these three lines into your onCreate method:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/hallo.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```